# Heroku: Can I configure Heroku to do an incremental build on my Python / Django application?

Tags: git, heroku, build

I've a very big/large application, I'm doing some tiny changes, when I push using:

```
git push heroku master
```

I see that the full app start deploying, not just the modified files! is there a way to push just the single files!

P.S:
**Edit 1:** I changed the title
**Edit 2:** Is there a way to store many commits locally before pushing them into one single commit due to the question above!

Regards!

Comment: What language is your application written in?

Comment: @dpassage Python/Django and Im using Heroku

Comment: You *are* pushing just the changed files. That's how `git push` works, by sending deltas. But Heroku builds a *whole new instance* of your application each time you deploy. Your question should really be something like, "Can I configure Heroku to do an incremental build on my Python / Django application?" I'm not sure what the answer to that is.

Comment: @Chris True, thank you for the insight, I should change my question title! and add a secondary one!